# Kotlin equivalent of Scala ListBuffer

Tags: scala, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin and trying to convert an app written in Scala to Kotlin. In Scala there is the ListBuffer from `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`. Is there an equivalent in Kotlin? I tried importing `com.sun.tools.javac.util.ListBuffer` but I would get an error when I try to compile: `Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.compiler' which does not export package 'com.sun.tools.javac.util'`?

Comment: probably you need `MutableList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use `MutableList` instead for the same purposes. Though I should note that Scala and Kotlin collections are very different in general, e.g. Kotlin prefers read-only collections to actually immutable ones and doesn't have a direct equivalent of Scala `List`. So if you are hoping to take a Scala library/app and change class names, it won't work unless your app is very trivial.